# SQLMembershipProvider - Adding membership to an existing database. Setting permissions

Tags: .net, sql-server, authentication, web-config, sqlmembershipprovider

I am adding membership-related schemas to an existing database (lets call it myDatabase) following [those instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506052241/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/040506-1.aspx).

As a results the number of tables, views and stored procedures are being created in myDatabase.

The next step is to modify web.config for the application to use CustomizedMembershipProvider

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomizedMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
         <add name="CustomizedMembershipProvider"
              type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
              connectionStringName="MyDBConnectionString" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Then we also need to specify the connection string like:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="MyDB" MyDBConnectionString ="..." />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**Here is my question:**

1. Should I use different connection string to the one the application uses? As is there a need to create a new user in the database with permissions related specifically to the membership objects?
2. Once the connection string is specified with the User ID etc., do I need to grant permissions for that user for those newly created objects? Would that be for stored procedures only or also tables and views?

**EDIT:**
I noticed that there was a set of roles created in the database along with the membership object. So it is a matter of assigning the user to the proper role(s). The roles are the likes of

```
aspnet_Membership_FullAccess
aspnet_Personalization_FullAccess
etc...
```

So the only the first part of the question remains in place. So is there a point in creating a new database user (so separate db connection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked it up a bit,

1. The standard connection can be used
2. In terms of permissions it looks
   like it is a matter of assigning the
   database user to the
   aspnet_Membership_FullAccess role ([other roles if you require privileges related to them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164596(VS.80).aspx))

Answer (score 2):

Some good texts about Membership Provider:

- [Examining ASP.NET 2.0's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513220018/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx)
- [Membership and Role Providers in ASP.NET 2.0 Part](http://odetocode.com/Articles/427.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1. It's perfectly okay to use the same user/database as your application.
2. I don't know, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the same connection string for performance reasons. Using the same connection string as your application will allow more efficient connection pooling.